# Sharepoint list "Load more items" issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view

I created a custom list view with these two filters active

[image]

But for some reason it is not possible to load all the items at once (limit of 100 per page), we have to click on the "Load more items" button multiple times. When the list is loaded, after a few seconds, a refresh occurs and all items disappear, returning to the initial state of "Load more items".
[image]

Does anyone know why this happens?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The default limit of 100 items per page in SharePoint Online list views. When you try to load more items, the page refreshes and returns to the initial state of "Load more items". Please follow these steps:

Go to "List settings", under the "Views" section, click on the view you want to modify.
Scroll down to the "Item Limit" section and increase the number of items to display per page.